# QSlider stuck though still emitting sliderMoved

Tags: pyqt

In my PyQt4-based program, QSliders (with signals sliderMoved and sliderReleased connected to callables) sometimes "freeze", i.e. they don't move anymore when trying to drag them with the mouse, even though sliderMoved and sliderReleased are still emitted.

This behaviour happens seemingly randomly, sometimes after running the program for hours -- making it more or less impossible to reproduce and test.

Any help to solve this issue would be welcome.

EDIT: This is with PyQt 4.10.4 on Python 3.4 and Windows 7.

Comment: I have never seen this but maybe others have. You could add information about OS, Python version, Qt version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging I am pretty sure that this was due to calling a GUI slot from a separate thread, which (I knew) is forbidden.  Fixing this to use a proper signal-slot approach seems to have fixed the issue.

After calling the `patch` function defined below, **all** slot calls are wrapped by a wrapper that checks that they are called only from the GUI thread -- a warning is printed otherwise.  This is how I found the culprit.

```
import functools
import sys
import threading
import traceback

from PyQt4.QtCore import QMetaMethod
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget


SLOT_CACHE = {}


def patch():
    """Check for calls to widget slots outside of the main thread.
    """
    qwidget_getattribute = QWidget.__getattribute__
    def getattribute(obj, name):
        attr = qwidget_getattribute(obj, name)
        if type(obj) not in SLOT_CACHE:
            meta = qwidget_getattribute(obj, "metaObject")()
            SLOT_CACHE[type(obj)] = [
                method.signature().split("(", 1)[0]
                for method in map(meta.method, range(meta.methodCount()))
                if method.methodType() == QMetaMethod.Slot]
        if (isinstance(attr, type(print)) and # Wrap builtin functions only.
                attr.__name__ in SLOT_CACHE[type(obj)]):
            @functools.wraps(
                attr, assigned=functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS + ("__self__",))
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                if threading.current_thread() is not threading.main_thread():
                    print("{}.{} was called out of main thread:".format(
                        type(obj), name), file=sys.stderr)
                    traceback.print_stack()
                return attr(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        else:
            return attr
    QWidget.__getattribute__ = getattribute
```